# Filling a double lawsuit to compel arbitration in both state and federal court?

Tags: united-states, civil-law, federal-courts, new-jersey, arbitration

Federal courts are authorized to hear cases when the case involves federal question jurisdiction. State courts, on the other hand, are authorized to hear civil cases when the case involves state law. Suppose one wishes to file a suit to compel arbitration in a matter that involves both state and federal law, can one submit overlapping lawsuit to federal & state court at the same time?

For example, suppose two parties have an executed contract with a binding arbitration clause. Party A believes that Party B is in violation of both federal and state law and wishes to force Party B to arbitrate both claims. Party B holds that the contract does not force them to arbitrate (let's say because it expired) and believes that they have not violated any laws.

Can Party A file a suit to compel arbitration in both federal and state court?

What if they file two lawsuits and the state court rules differently than the federal court?

Assuming Party A can only file one lawsuit at a time, what stops Party A from first filling a lawsuit in state court and if the court rules against them to file a suit in federal court on the federal question? Presumably, if the federal court rules in their favor it would override the state court's decision.

**Note**: Although the reason for each lawsuit is different (federal vs. state law), the underlying question of whether the parties are bound to arbitration is the same. In other words, if the federal court arrives at the conclusion that the parties are bound to arbitrate the federal question (for example, because they arrive at the conclusion that the contract didn't expire), the same logic would apply to the state question (and vice versa).

Comment: One court will certainly deny taking on the case, and if one’s not lucky, it will be decided without them having control over it after they filed.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do that?

Comment: @ohwilleke I can think of multiple reasons. On reason is that if one is pressed for time and is uncertain whether both the federal and the state suit will be accepted, it is not necessary to wait for one to be rejected before filling the other. By filling both at the same time, one can pursue the complaint that is accepted.

Comment: @S.O.S. State court always has concurrent jurisdiction over federal claims. And, if one is drafting a complaint one can state claims that are clearly enough federal to leave no room for dispute if you want a federal forum. Forum concerns are particularly weak when the merits will be decided in arbitration and not be the forum court.

Comment: @ohwilleke Meaning that there is a lower bar to acceptance when all is needed from the courts is an order to arbitrate (as appose to a ruling on the actual case)? Thanks!

Comment: @ohwilleke Ultimately, do you see any harm in filling a overlapping / parallel lawsuit? If one is pressed for time and needs at least one of the two lawsuits to be accepted I don't see how this could have any detrimental effect.

Comment: @S.o.S. Filing two lawsuits is almost guaranteed to be slower and more expensive than filing one lawsuit because it will generate lots of motion practice on collateral issues related to having filed two lawsuit.